# Understanding ARM Assembly Code

Tags: assembly, arm

Can anyone explain to me what this short program does?

```
ORIGIN 0x1000
one DEFW 13
two DEFW 29
three DEFW 0
ORIGIN 0x1010
ENTRY
ADR R0, one
LDR R1, [R0]
LDR R2, [R0, #4]
ADD R1, R2, R1
STR R1, [R0, #8]
SWI 2
```

If I'm thinking correctly, it adds 'one' to 'two' and places the result in 'three'. Am I correct?

Comment: Is this homework? Why did you obfuscate it? It's not useful to others if you do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

```
ORIGIN 0x1000          # Start at address 0x1000
one DEFW 13            # Allocate 4-bytes of space for a variable called one and set it to 13
two DEFW 29            # Allocate 4-bytes of space for a variable called two and set it to 29
three DEFW 0           # Allocate 4-bytes of space for a variable called three and set it to 0
ORIGIN 0x1010          # Skip ahead to address 0x1010 (this really leaves a 4-byte gap)
ENTRY                  # Mark next instruction as the begining of program
ADR R0, one            # Load address of one into R0
LDR R1, [R0]           # Load contents of one (pointed to but R0) into R1
LDR R2, [R0, #4]       # Load contents of two (pointed to but R0 + 4) into R2
ADD R1, R2, R1         # R1 = R2 + R1
STR R1, [R0, #8]       # Store R1 into three  (pointed to but R0 + 8)
SWI 2                  # Execute a software interrupt
```

or

```
three = one + two
```

Not sure about the 'SWI 2' It's probably something specific to your platform. Maybe just a generic end of program call.

Comment: +1: http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/pcheung/teaching/ee2_computing/swi.pdf seems to suggest that `SWI 2` would print to some kind of debug stream (at least on that system).

Comment: On some ARM systems SWI stands for "SoftWare Interrupt".

Comment: SWI is the software interrupt instruction. As @Pete Fordham says, what SWI 2 is depends on the platform.